# Install shield installer fails to install Microsoft .Net Core 3.1.4 Hosting Bundle when a newer version is already installed

Tags: asp.net-core, installation, deployment

So far I'm seeing it happen when 3.1.20 or higher is installed.  Installer says Installing Microsoft .Net Core 3.1.4 and prompts to reboot.  It always does this when the higher version is installed.

I'm in support as opposed to Development.  So far we've been uninstalling the newer version, installing 3.1.4, installing our software, and reinstalling 3.1.x

I'm wondering if there's any temporary "hack" to avoid the need to uninstall the newer version.  This may be updating some registry for version or updating some file and then reverting it back.

Also, if you know a way to avoid this in code, feel free to let me know and I'll pass it along to our Devs.  Thanks in advance.